# What do here mean "void" and "solid"?

Tags: word-meaning

A nonlinear filter, the median filter was used to reduce the noise in the images: the grey value of each voxel is substituted by the grey value of the voxels in the neighbourhood. For further data analysis, it was necessary to classify the volume pixels either in void or solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it should end *either as void or solid*.

Since the voxels (volume pixels) are three dimensional structures they can either be empty or full so *void* or *solid*. If they were just pixels and two dimensional they would probably be classified as either black or white.

Comment: Could you also please give a definition of "grey value"?

Comment: At least explain this sentence in easier words for me to understand it better.

Comment: I was assuming that since you gave a very technical example you were familiar with that area of science. Is that not true? The voxels in the original image were coloured using a grey scale from white to black so the grey value would have been a number indicating where they were on the scale probably from 0 to 255 or 0 to 1023